# Problem with Ansible command/shell "msg": "non-zero return code"

Tags: ansible

I have been banging my head against a wall for hours trying all sorts of combinations using examples on Stackoverflow. I want to register the output of the command to then check if the text "not running" is present before continuing with the play. Currently I have this in the play with the fatal error below. I've tried the ignore errors option but it doesn't move on.

```
- name: Check if Splunk is currently running or stopped
  ansible.builtin.shell: "/opt/splunk/bin/splunk status"
  register: splunk_status
  ignore_errors: yes
  until: splunk_status.stdout is search('not running')
  retries: 20
  delay: 2
```

Result:

```
TASK [splunk-upgrade : Check if Splunk is currently running or stopped] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ans-host1]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 1, "changed": true, "cmd": "/opt/splunk/bin/splunk status", "delta": "0:00:00.004080", "end": "2022-10-19 16:10:20.776424", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 3, "start": "2022-10-19 16:10:20.772344", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "splunkd is not running.", "stdout_lines": ["splunkd is not running."]}
...ignoring
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was because of an issue writing to stdout due to the previous step in the play. I combined it down to one step:

---

```
- name: Stop Splunk
  ansible.builtin.shell: /opt/splunk/bin/splunk stop
  register: splunk_status
  until: ("Done" in splunk_status.stdout) or ("not running" in splunk_status.stdout)
  retries: 20
  delay: 2
```